# Display Listed as Laptop

Tags: 12.04, display

I'm using 12.04 on a Desktop--I installed with a CD; I installed by USB earlier, while Wubi produced an error (I only tried this method once).  While running Precise from the CD or USB, the display was fine--it was listed as a Dell 15-inch.  Do I need to get a new HDD?; I didn't have this problem on the old drive.

Comment: So, you've installed Ubuntu on a laptop, and it's display is recognized as such. What is the problem? Also, thanks for sharing your experience, but is there a question?

Comment: I installed on a Desktop, but in Displays Hardware, the screen is labelled as laptop instead of the Desktop it is; the error in the screen is that the "U" in "Ubuntu" is cut off.  I was wondering what I need to do to make this problem disappear so that the screen is listed as the CD- and USB-run screen appear.  I ran "sudo laptop-detect -v" and it said "We're not on a laptop".

Comment: I also have something else to report, when I try to download the browser Opera, Linux tries to open the file in the Software Center.  The Center reports that the file is the wrong architecture--amd64; the file I burned from MS Windows was for i386 Desktop.  Maybe this fact indicates an error besides just what the Display problem alone poses.

Comment: Opera has [i386 installers](http://www.opera.com/download/guide/?os=linux-i386&ver=12.14&local=y).

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is common for (older) systems running integrated graphics chipsets rather than discreet video cards, particularly when the chipset was predominantly used in laptops. My server (which has an ATI Rage XL integrated graphics chipset) displays the the monitor as "Laptop" in 12.04.